# WPF How to layout multiple containers to use in same Window

Tags: wpf

I'm new-ish to WPF. I am building a program that connects to some external hardware to provide a computer based diagnostic interface. Depending on which external hardware is connected I need to configure the user interface slightly differently.

I need to show a series of controls and text blocks that will be common to every device, but 50% of the controls, and their layout will be different for each device.

What I would like to do is to create a standard main window that contains the common controls. But have a section of that window where I can call up programmatically the relevant view.

Is it possible in Visual studio to layout separate Panels / Views (Grid or Stack Containers etc...) as separate documents then display them within an existing Window as required? if so how best should I do this?

Comment: You'd probably build device-specific DataTemplates or UserControls.

Comment: If the content is the same for all devices and the only difference is whether it should be shown or not, you can just show/hide specific controls based on the device. If not, DataTemplates or UserControls are the way, as @Clements mentioned.